# Css design issue

Tags: html, css

For some reason my background color does not cover the entire page width on my mobile device, However, it looks fine on a regular desktop. I cannot find the problem.

[image: Problem screenshot]

Here is my style.css:

```
@media only screen and (min-width : 250px) and (max-width : 780px)
{

#pageHeader{
    border:none;
    background-color:"background-color:#F5F5DC";
}


#pageHeader nav {

   height:300px;
   width:100%;
}

#pageHeader nav ul {
padding-left:0;
width:100%;
}

#pageHeader nav ul li {
width:100%;
text-align:center;
margin-left:25px;;
}

#pageheader nav a:link, #pageHeader nav a:visited {
height: 60px;
padding: 5px 23px;
text-decoration: none;
dislay: block;
width:100%;
}
#pageHeader img{
    width: 100%;
    height: auto;
    margin-bottom: 3%;
}


}
```

Here is my html:

```
!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style/style.css" type="text/css" media="screen" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>About Us</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="pageHeader" style="background-color:#F5F5DC">
        <a href="index.php"><img src="style/logo.jpg" name="logo" width="431" height="94" alt=""/></a>
        <br />
        <br />
        <nav>
             <ul>
                <li ><a href="index.php">Home</a></li>
                <li style="margin-left:25px"><a href="#">All Products</a></li>
                <li style="margin-left:25px"><a href="#">Blog Using Ruby</a></li>
                <li style="margin-left:25px"><a href="#">User Javascript Page</a></li>
                <li style="margin-left:25px"><a href="#">Submit Concerns using Perl</a></li>
                <li class="active" style="margin-left:25px"><a href="#">About Us using HTML5</a></li>
                <li style="margin-left:25px"><a href="#">Asp Help Pages</a></li>
                <li style="margin-left:25px;"><a href="cart.php"><img src="style/cartimage.jpg" name="shopping cart" /></a></li>
            </ul>
        </nav>
    </div>
    </div>
    <h1 align="center">About Us</h1> </br> </br>

    <div align="center" id="pageBody">
        <table width="100%" border="0" cellpadding="6">
            <tbody>
                <tr>
                    <td> Code omitted </td>
                </tr>
          </tbody>
        </table>

        <div id="pageFooter">
        Copyright |<a href="storeadmin/admin_login.php">Admin Log In </a>      
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: maybe have a look at this line `background-color:"background-color:#F5F5DC";` that should be `background-color:#F5F5DC;`

Comment: @web-tiki Thanks I didnt see that but still a no go

Comment: Is the HTML complete - it stops at the shopping cart icon, whereas the content after this seems to be that which does not have the background. Can you post more of your HTML?

Comment: @pwdst Posted complete code

Comment: I have re-formatted your HTML code in order to make it more readable - I assume that the missing angle bracket in the doctype declaration is simply a copy paste error (but you will definitely need to fix that if it is missing in your code). You also have duplicate end tags for the pageHeader div element which may be causing problems.

Comment: @pwdst I took at the <br /> tags and still nothing. However, when I set the background for #pageHeader ul li it does look a little wider in that section but still off.

Comment: @pwdst I deleted the extra div but still same problem. I want the top logo to be above the list, but do you think its an alignment error?

Comment: I can't replicate your issue with the code posted - probably due to the missing CSS for default/other viewport sizes. Is this a live project that you could post a link to? Which browser(s) are you seeing the issue on - is this mobile devices, or are you able to replicate it using desktop browser(s) at "mobile" viewport sizes?

Comment: @pwdst Heres a link: http://dmcgee0.ddns.net/NewPHPProject/AboutUs.html Also, only on mobile devices, I am using Android Default Web browser, and Iphone4 safari. Also, no I can only see it on mobile devices

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove the explicit height on the nav element - let the flow content dictate that rather than setting it explicitly. If you clear fix the floats in the unordered list using the CSS-

```
.group:after {
    visibility: hidden;
    display: block;
    content: "";
    clear: both;
    height: 0;
    }
```

(See http://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/clear-fix/)

The list will take the height of its contents.

You will also want to remove the margin left on the list item elements (these are at 100% **plus** the 25px margin), replacing it with padding-left and setting box-sizing: border-box on the list items (or just set the margin to zero when at a smaller viewport width as your design doesn't seem to need it).

The unordered list will need to look something like this-

```
<ul class="group">
   <li><a href="index.php">Home</a></li>
   <li><a href="#">All Products</a></li>
   <li><a href="#">Blog Using Ruby</a></li>
   <li><a href="#">User Javascript Page</a></li>
   <li><a href="#">Submit Concerns using Perl</a></li>
   <li class="active"><a href="#">About Us using HTML5</a></li>
   <li><a href="#">Asp Help Pages</a></li>
   <li><a href="cart.php"><img src="style/cartimage.jpg" name="shopping cart" /></a></li>
</ul>
```

In either case you should remove the inline margin-left: 25px styles - you will find it much more maintainable to keep these externally in your CSS.

Comment: @user3339242 It's also worth mentioning, and I'm kicking myself for not saying this earlier, that you probably just want to take the float off by setting float: none (see https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/float) in your media query styles given the vertical list required at this viewport list.

Answer (score 2):

Look that you have an extra  tag when you close your

```
<div id="pageHeader" style="background-color:#F5F5DC">
```

If you are using more code, and floating some tags, dont forget to put the "overflow:hidden" in the container that "contains" the tags floated!

Comment: and, if you are going to use and external css doc, it is not necesary to add style to you div tags!  eg: "background-color:#F5F5DC"

Comment: The extra closing div tag isn't the problem here - although it is *a* problem. I also agree on moving the inline CSS styles out to the stylesheet.

Comment: @Johny Could you explain in detail the overflow:hidden because that got rid of the white space!

Comment: @user3339242 Overflow hidden acts as a way of forcing the container to clear floated child contents. This forms one of the steps required to both remove the white space, and the page scrolling beyond 100% horizontally. See my answer for more.

Comment: Sory being late! I think the Q was already answered! Good Luck!